# Error while doing UPSERT in Sqlite 3.34 - Error: near "DO": syntax error

Tags: sqlite, insert-update, upsert

I am trying to load a daily CSV load file into a `main` table, so that all new records are inserted and all existing records are updated. I am using [`UPSERT`](https://sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html) feature of Sqlite for this purpose.

Here is my shell script.

```sh
LOAD_FILE="/tmp/main.csv"
LOAD_TABLE="tbl_tmp_main"
MAIN_TABLE="tbl_main"
COLUMNS="t_id, t_col1, t_col2"


CREATE_TABLE_QUERY="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $LOAD_TABLE; CREATE TABLE $LOAD_TABLE AS SELECT $COLUMNS FROM $MAIN_TABLE WHERE false"
LOAD_TABLE_QUERY=".separator ','\n.import '$LOAD_FILE' $LOAD_TABLE"
UPSERT_TABLE_QUERY="
    INSERT INTO $MAIN_TABLE($COLUMNS) SELECT $COLUMNS FROM $LOAD_TABLE
    ON CONFLICT(t_id) DO UPDATE
    SET
        t_col1 = excluded.t_col1,
        t_col2 = excluded.t_col2
    ;
"

echo ""
echo "$CREATE_TABLE_QUERY" | sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite3            # <-- This works
echo "[INFO] Temporary Table Created."

echo "$LOAD_TABLE_QUERY" | sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite3              # <-- This works
echo "[INFO] Data Loaded into Temporary Table."

echo "$UPSERT_TABLE_QUERY" | sqlite3 mydatabase.sqlite3            # <-- This errors out
echo "[INFO] Records Inserted/Updated."
echo ""
```

Here is the error.

```
Error: near line 2: near "DO": syntax error
```

I tried to check the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html), but I am not sure what is wrong in the query above. Can somebody point out why it isnt working.

Here is my sqlite version

```
-> sqlite3 --version
3.34.1 2021-01-20 14:10:07 10e20c0b43500cfb9bbc0eaa061c57514f715d87238f4d835880cd846b9ebd1f
```

Comment: Check the documentation for this paragraph: *"2.1. Parsing Ambiguity"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is due to `Parsing Ambiguity` as mentioned in the documentation. You need to add `WHERE true` as part of the SELECT clause and that should fix it.

Here is your updated UPSERT query.

```sql
INSERT INTO $MAIN_TABLE($COLUMNS) SELECT $COLUMNS FROM $LOAD_TABLE  WHERE true
--                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
ON CONFLICT(t_id) DO UPDATE
SET
    t_col1 = excluded.t_col1,
    t_col2 = excluded.t_col2
;
```

Here is the section in [Docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_upsert.html).

> Parsing Ambiguity
>
> When the INSERT statement to which the UPSERT is attached takes its values from a SELECT statement, there is a potential parsing ambiguity. The parser might not be able to tell if the "ON" keyword is introducing the UPSERT or if it is the ON clause of a join. To work around this, the SELECT statement should always include a WHERE clause, even if that WHERE clause is just "WHERE true".
>
> Ambiguous use of ON:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2
> ON CONFLICT(x) DO UPDATE SET y=excluded.y;
> ```
>
> Ambiguity resolved using a WHERE clause:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO t1 SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE true
> ON CONFLICT(x) DO UPDATE SET y=excluded.y;
> ```